# Pug Express req.user Interpolation

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am having a really hard time accessing a variable in Pug from Express.

My route looks like:

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile/profile', {user: req.user});
});
```

My template looks like:

```
          .card
            .card-body
              h4.card-title Local Profile
              if (user)
                p.card-text
                  strong.pr-2 ID: !{user.userEmail}
                  br
                  br
                  strong.pr-2 Name:
                  = user
                  br
                  br
                  strong.pr-2 Email:
                  = user
                  br
                  br
                  strong.pr-2 Password:
                  span.text-muted= user
                  a.btn.btn-default(href="/profile/edit") Edit
                p.card-text
                small.text-muted Last login
                = user
```

The user object looks like:

```
{UID: 5, userEmail: "rtester@testing.com", userPassword: "bd4eb56b41fc3663dfe2761ff34621a544ecfe27", userLastLogin: "2017-11-20T22:18:13.000Z", userToken: "cae45ae7e68ef8024d4ad5b56c68f263"}
```

If I include just user without stringifying, then I get Object object.  If I stringify I can output the object, but trying to access a property in the object gives me nothing.

But if I

```
console.log(x.userEmail)
```

after

```
var x = !{JSON.stringify(user)}
```

then I get the property.

Any help would be fantastic!!

Answer (score 0):

use  `user.userEmail` instead of `!{user.userEmail}`
this worked fine for me,

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var u = {UID: 5, userEmail: "rtester@testing.com", userPassword: "bd4eb56b41fc3663dfe2761ff34621a544ecfe27", userLastLogin: "2017-11-20T22:18:13.000Z", userToken: "cae45ae7e68ef8024d4ad5b56c68f263"}
  res.render('index', { user: u });
});
```

,

```
html
  head
    title= user.userEmail
  body
    h1= user.userEmail
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.   Just blank space.   No error, it didn't render to the view.

Comment: worked for me using directly user.userEmail without !{}

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The issue was actually Passport and the Sessions.  The req.user object being created had a nested property that when passed directly to the view had other "stuff" in it that I couldn't see and didn't show when doing a console.log to the browser, but I could see on the backend.  I found this question that helped.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670322/cannot-get-properties-of-req-user

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually had nothing to do with Pug or Express.  It was with the way that Passport was setting the req.user variable after finding the user using Bookshelf.js.

There were some additional nested attributes in the object.  This separate answer led me to a solution to isolate the information I needed.  [Cannot get properties of req.user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670322/cannot-get-properties-of-req-user)

The way to access the information in Pug is the same as laid out in the docs.